# Querying by composite key with a timestamp as a clustering column

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I have a composite key with a partition key that is a uuid and a composite key that is a timestamp. Here's my entity.

```
@Table("send")
class Send(
        @PrimaryKey val key: SendKey,
        @Column("activity_id")
        var activityId: UUID

) : Serializable

@PrimaryKeyClass
class SendKey(
        @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "user_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
        val senderId: UUID,

        @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "created_at", ordinal = 3, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
        val createdAt: Instant,

        @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "target_post_id", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
        val targetUserId: UUID
): Serializable
```

Now, I'm trying to retrieve the unique record using `sendRepository.findById(SendKey(userId = userId, createdAt = createdAt!!, targetUserId = postId))` but I don't get any results.

Here's the Repository

```
@Repository
interface SendRepository: ReactiveCassandraRepository<Send, SendKey> {
}
```

Where did I go wrong? 
I'm using Jackson for parsing a default date format. Why can't I find a matching record when I specify the right format and timestamp down to microsecond precision?

Comment: In SendKey you have ordinal = 3 on attribute createdAt. Does this also reflect the state in the table (createdAt is on the last place in the key?)? Can you also share the log you receive from Cassandra? Is there any error or just empty result?